# Radio button checked property fails in function - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have encountered a problem where checking a radio button using JavaScript does not work when used in a called function, and I have not a clue why this happens - see working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vulcan/0zykejvh/3/

I have tried several forms of doing this, such as

```
document.getElementById("id").checked= true
```

and

```
var radioVar = document.getElementById("id")
radioVar.checked = true
```

I would rather not have to use jQuery as I have no idea how to use it

Comment: Your code works fine, you are just loading it in the wrong place in your fiddle (see the options in the top left corner). Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/0zykejvh/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's becausse the element doesn't exist, put the js in a script at the bottom of your body
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0zykejvh/5/)

```
<script></script></body>
```

Comment: Does the body of an HTML document load linearly? What I mean is that if i put a <script> tag at the bottom of a document would every element above it have loaded?

Comment: sorry for the delay in replying, the answer is yes. the script in the head will look for an element that does not exist yet, where as a script just before the closing body tag will have the elements ready to manipulate. if using js from the head wrap it in a function like this  `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { // // doc ready actions here // // } to make sure that everything is loaded and ready. if using jquery wrap it in `$(document).ready(function(){ // // doc ready actions here // //});`